# How to create TypeScript library with Webpack without bundling

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, webpack

I am working on a React component package with Typescript and NPM. I learned that the best approach is to generate individual .js and .d.ts files instead of bundling them to a single bundle.js. However, I do not know how to achieve this with Webpack. It looks like Webpack always bundles everything together. I cannot use just tsc transpiler since I have styles in LESS format and need to process them and bundle them into one single style.css. Can Webpack with ts-loader be configured in the way I described or do I need a different tooling?

**EDIT**: I have found [this thread](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5866) on Webpack issue board that requests exactly what I am discribing and it looks like it is not yet possible.

Comment: You could take a look at `tsup` — makes it so simple to bundle an app https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsup and I find it much easier to use than webpack. `tsup src/index.ts --dts` is all you need to start

Answer (score 0):

You can seek solutions in existing React TS component libraries, like https://github.com/yocontra/react-responsive. `react-responsive` uses `typescript-declaration-webpack-plugin`.